# C# - Class with List<> of other Classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class, that has several elements of normal types, like int, String, etc.
It also has several elements that are various lists of other classes, that could be empty or have 1 to many items.

I have a function that I call with a generic type of the parent class, and I want to analyze data that could be in the sub elements, without knowing the types.

I am getting the parent members with the following code:

```
var getProperty = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.
                  CallSite<Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, 
              object, object>>
                 .Create(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.
                  Binder.GetMember(0, property.Name, thisObject.GetType(), new[] 
                  {
                      Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(0, null)
                  }));

var thisValue = getProperty.Target(getProperty, thisObject);
```

I get the value into the var thisValue.  At this point if I determine the underlying type of thisValue is a type of list, how can I grab the type of the list contents?

Here is the actual function....I can't seem to get it formatted nicely.

```
        public static bool ObjectIsLike<T>(this T thisObject, T compareObject, params object[] argumentsToExclude)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < argumentsToExclude.Length - 1; counter++)
        {
            argumentsToExclude[counter] = argumentsToExclude[counter].ToString().ToUpper();
        }
        bool objectIsLike = true;
        foreach (var property in thisObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            string fieldName = property.Name;

            if (!argumentsToExclude.Contains(fieldName.ToUpper()))
            {
                try
                {
                    var getProperty = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, object>>.Create(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember(0, property.Name, thisObject.GetType(), new[] { Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(0, null) }));
                    var thisValue = getProperty.Target(getProperty, thisObject);
                    getProperty = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, object>>.Create(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember(0, property.Name, compareObject.GetType(), new[] { Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(0, null) }));
                    var compareValue = getProperty.Target(getProperty, compareObject);
                    if (!(compareValue == null && thisValue == null))
                    {
                        if (compareValue == null || thisValue == null)
                            objectIsLike = false;
                        else
                            if (compareValue.GetType().FullName.Contains("List"))
                            {
                                //Ignore Lists
                            }
                            else
                                if (!compareValue.Equals(thisValue))
                                    {
                                        objectIsLike = false;
                                    }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    objectIsLike = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return objectIsLike;
    }
```

Comment: This is a pretty strong sign that something is wrong in your program.  It's hard to say without knowing what you're actually trying to do, but most likely you should be leveraging polymorphism such that the caller doesn't *care* what the specific type of the object is, but instead you'll know that it implements an interface or inherits from a common base class that provides the functionality that you do need.

Comment: I want to be able to build generic method that I can send an two objects in and compare every element to see if they are equal.  I don't want to build method for every single object type, so I am using generics.  This works find on standard element types likeints and strings..etc..but when an object has a subobject or alist of subobjets, I need to be able compare the objects by recursively calling this sam function.

Comment: If you have a collection of objects and you want to know if they're all equal just have the method require a comparer, or require that the items implement `IComparable`, so that you can compare them.  This is already a solved problem though, just take a look at, for example, how sorting is done in generic collections.  There are a few thousand examples of this all over the web.

Comment: I could, but there are tons and tons of examples out there; I even described how you can go about finding some of them.  You shouldn't *be* working with lists of objects, that's my *point*, and it's the reason that you use generics in the first place.  You have lists of the generic argument, not of *anything*.

Comment: Looked this up, and this will work, I will have to add this to every object in my project, and any future project.  I am looking to create a single function extension to do this. Trying to put formatted code in for what the function looks like now.

Comment: And I am not working with lists of objects, I am working with lists of specific items, I just put objects as a generic term.

Answer (score 0):

would GetType() work for you?
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass1 c1 = new MyClass1();

```
        foreach (var s in c1.pp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetType());    
        }
        Console.Read();
    }


}


public class MyClass1
{
    public MyClass2 p;
    public List<object> pp;

    public MyClass1()
    {
        p = new MyClass2();
        pp = new List<object>();
        pp.Add(new MyClass2());
        pp.Add(new MyClass3());
        pp.Add(new MyClass4());
    }
}



public class MyClass2
{
    public List<object> ppp;

    public MyClass2()
    {
        ppp = new List<object>();
        ppp.Add(new MyClass3());
        ppp.Add(new MyClass4());
    }
}

public class MyClass3
{
    public int v;
}

public class MyClass4
{
    public int v;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, I provided a copy of the function I am working on.  The get type on the variable in question returns a type of list, so I need to get the type of the contents of the list.